# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined VueJS Parcel

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, parceljs

I have this:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
import HSCore from './components/assets/js/hs.core.js'
```

Yet I still get this:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object.parcelRequire.client/components/assets/js/hs.core.js (hs.core.js:177)
```

Why

`import jQuery from 'jquery'` does actually import jQuery (via `console.log(jQuery)`), but my other JS file is having problems accessing it(?). This is in a Vue file using Parcel loader.

hs.core.js file:

```
(function ($) {
...

})(jQuery); //<-- line 177
```

Comment: you `import`ed something to one js file, the others still cannot access it, unless you have registered it globally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
const { $, jQuery } = require('jquery');
global.$ = $;
global.jQuery = jQuery;

require( './components/assets/js/hs.core.js');//<-- this made it work with all the above code too

// $ object now exists:  $(“#el”)
// jQuery now exists:  jQuery(“#el”)
```

Comment: This worked once I imported my file like so: require( './components/assets/js/hs.core.js');` With your code above

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
global.jQuery = require('/assets/js/script');
var $ = global.jQuery;
window.jQuery = $;
```